# Why the macro value is 0 instead of 1?

Tags: c, macros

here `base->left` is `NULL`, and `base->right->height` is `0`:

```
((((base->left ? base->left->height : -1)) > ((base->right ? base->right->height : -1))) 
? 
((base->left ? base->left->height : -1) + 1) 
: 
((base->right ? base->right->height : -1) + 1))
```

IMO the result of the above expression should be `1`,

but it turns out it's `0` when I print it out.

Anyone knows the reason?

Is it a bug of gcc 4.3.2?

**UPDATE**

how the expression come?

```
#define MAX_PLUS_1(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a + 1) : (b + 1))
#define BINARY_TREE_HEIGHT(node) (node ? node->height : -1)
#define BINARY_TREE_SYN_HEIGHT(left, right) \
    MAX_PLUS_1(\
        BINARY_TREE_HEIGHT(left),\
        BINARY_TREE_HEIGHT(right)\
    )
```

it's really `BINARY_TREE_SYN_HEIGHT(base->left, base->right)`

And the problem is gone if I replace `MAX_PLUS_1` with function:

```
int MAX_PLUS_1(int a, int b){
    return (((a) > (b)) ? (a + 1) : (b + 1));
}
```

Comment: Yes, there must be a bug in the ternary operator in GCC ... not. [First Rule of programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: @Brian Roach,I'm serious, I've worked on this expression for about one hour, I don't see why it's `0`

Comment: Could you post the full macro definition, along with an example of use? The issue is most likely an error in the specifics of the macro definition.

Comment: How do you print it out?

Comment: I just finished reindenting this and stepping through part by part. I can verify that the code should indeed return `1`.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore ,tried both in `gdb` and with `printf`

Comment: @gregj ,updated with that part .

Comment: @Mysticial ,can you try it with gcc?

Comment: I can't right now since I'm not booted into Linux at the moment.

Comment: What type is the `height` field? I wonder if this is a signed / unsigned thing?

Comment: @AAT,`height` is `uint32_t`,seems you find the reason,but why??

Comment: @JeRog: based on what @AAT said, `-1 = 2^32 - 1 > 0`, which makes your first condition "true" rather than false, as you would expect.

Comment: @mange ,so when you compare `unsigned` and `signed`,both are converted to `unsigned`? I thought both would be converted to `signed`,my bad..

Comment: @JeRog: The ternary operator must have a return type, so in this case it takes the only specified return type: `uint32_t`. For the `signed`/`unsigned` comparison case gcc should issue a warning (which you should have enabled).

Comment: @JeRog: In this case, yes, because the -1 was automatically "promoted" by the ternary operator. If you were to compare a `uint32_t` to an `int32_t`, though, gcc would warn you about it (this often happens to me in loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From additional information in our Comments discussion, your `height` field is unsigned. That means that when you try to compare it to -1 you end up in trouble - `(uint32_t)-1 == 0xFFFF_FFFF` = Very Big Number, so the 'left' branch gets chosen over the 'right' branch at some point when you don't expect it to.

Writing `MAX_PLUS_1()` as a function solves, or perhaps rather hides, this problem because you use `int` for the parameters. That means the comparison is done between the `height` value and `(int)-1`, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is badly designed. The fact that it works as a function, let me just suspect that this comes from the multiple evaluation of your macro arguments.

- don't ever have macros that evaluate their arguments twice. If the argument has side effects you are screwed
- always put parenthesis around your macro arguments. Depending on the arguments when called, operator precedence may give you something quite different than you think
- whenever this is possible simply use an `inline` function instead of a macro. This is as efficient, has type checking and guarantees that arguments are only evaluated once.
- in your particular case there is no reason at all to have the `+1` inside the macro. Factor it outside the macro or function call.
- you don't seem to control the types that you are using very well. you say your `height` field is an unsigned type but you give us a function call that has `int` parameters.
- *Edit:* usually `uint32_t` is not well suitable as an application type. why 32 bit why not 64? The best standard unsigned type for "sizes", "length" and stuff like that is usually `size_t`. Let the system decide what type it handles best.

Comment: Is it always the case that the `signed` will be conoverted to `unsigned` when you compare `unsigned` with `signed`,is it possible the other way around?

Comment: practically speaken, yes `signed` goes to `unsigned`. there might be weird architectures out there where the sign bit extends the bits of an `unsigned`. When all possible values of `unsigned` fit in `signed` it would the way you had expect. Best is not to make assumptions about this and to have a proper type for the things you are trying to compare.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your variables aren't what you think they are.

If you replace those with values to test the ternary, it indeed prints `1`

```
((((0 ? 1 : -1)) > ((1 ? 0 : -1))) 
?
((0 ? 0 : -1) + 1)
:        
((1 ? 0 : -1) + 1));
```